# how can i improve my multi threading usage to decrease run time, python

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization

### Machine Info

```
cpu_num 8 CPUs
cpu_speed   2826 MHz
mem_total   8173980 KB
swap_total  16777208 KB
```

### Benchmarking

When I increase the number of threads the performances gains i get look like (the numbers are averaged over 10 runs)

```
Number of Threads   Time
1                   1.322187
2                   0.789151
3                   0.72232
5                   0.613691
10                 0.558912
40                 0.531966
```

snapshot from top while running the code

```
top - 01:40:42 up 7 days, 13:24,  9 users,  load average: 0.34, 0.22, 0.27
Tasks: 364 total,   2 running, 362 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 28.2%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 71.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8173980k total,  7437664k used,   736316k free,   224748k buffers
Swap: 16777208k total,   149244k used, 16627964k free,  6374428k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                              
20365 ben.long  15   0  723m 208m 4224 S 226.2  2.6   0:37.28 python26                            
19948 ben.long  15   0 10996 1256  764 R  0.7  0.0   0:03.84 top                                                                  4420 ben.long  15   0  106m 3776 1360 R  0.0  0.0   0:03.06 sshd                                                                
 4421 ben.long  15   0 64320 1628 1180 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.07 bash                                                                 4423 ben.long  15   0 64320 1596 1180 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 bash                                                                
19949 ben.long  15   0 64308 1552 1136 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 bash
```

### Code

the stripped down code looks like

```
from threading import Thread

class testit(Thread):
   def __init__ (self,i):
      Thread.__init__(self)
   def run(self):
      some_task()#do processor heavy task

num_threads_to_use = 10
thread_list = []

for i in range (0,num_threads_to_use):
   current = testit(i)
   thread_list.append(current)
   current.start()

for thread in thread_list:
   thread.join()
```

### Questions

1. Should I be using the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module instead of the threading module?
2. Is there a way to improve the solution below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason behind a non linear increment of performance as the number of threads approach the number of cores might lie in this:

```
some_task()#do processor heavy task
```

The GIL is released around I/O heavy operations; if some_task() is CPU bound you are just occupying the GIL one thread at the time, thus sacrificing the benefit of threads (and maybe losing time in too many context switches ).

From http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html:

> The Python interpreter is not fully thread-safe. In order to support multi-threaded Python programs, there’s a global lock, called the global interpreter lock or GIL, that must be held by the current thread before it can safely access Python objects. Without the lock, even the simplest operations could cause problems in a multi-threaded program: for example, when two threads simultaneously increment the reference count of the same object, the reference count could end up being incremented only once instead of twice.
>
> Therefore, the rule exists that only the thread that has acquired the global interpreter lock may operate on Python objects or call Python/C API functions. In order to support multi-threaded Python programs, the interpreter regularly releases and reacquires the lock — by default, every 100 bytecode instructions (this can be changed with sys.setcheckinterval()). The lock is also released and reacquired around potentially blocking I/O operations like reading or writing a file, so that other threads can run while the thread that requests the I/O is waiting for the I/O operation to complete.

I might be wrong, butis my guess that threads share the same GIL, but processes don't.
Try with the multiprocessing module instead.

Comment: So...multiprocessing might help because each process will have it's own interpreter and GIL?

Comment: The whole point of the Global Interpreter is to avoid a race condition between threads - a situation in which one thread manipulate another threads's shared data. Using different processes might help because processes don't need a global lock, but I am not 100% sure about this one. Processes take a longer time to create and to switch to when confronted to threads, this is why the latter are usually called lightweight processes.

Comment: @martineau - yes. There can be problems efficiently sharing the GIL in some situations, especially when cores are at %100. Dave Beazely had some nice presentations on this: http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/

Comment: Only threads can acquire the GIL. If your not using threads, your not using the GIL.  Using fork or multiprocess won't bring the GIL into play unless the child processes are using threading.  Even then you have a GIL per python process (the GIL is not shared across processes).

Comment: @JimB: Thanks for the link. Beazley and I go way back -- he wrote the first Python book I ever bought. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing some CPU intensive task, only way in python to speed up that is to use multiple processes.

Other alternatives are

- Use different implementation of python e.g. [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) or [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)
- Write CPU intensive code as C modules